# Passing parameters to api

Tags: php, arrays, api, parameters

I want to pass an api a few parameters. The api documentation says that it should be passed in this way :

```
attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}
```

I am trying to achieve this in php through the following code this but its not working:

```
$params = array('filename' => "@" . realpath($filename), 
'parent' => array('id' => $parent_id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use PHP's own `StdClass` or your own class to represent `JSON` objects in PHP.
this is an exact replication of the `JSON` string in your question:

```
$att = new StdClass;
$att->name = "tigers.jpeg";
$att->parent = new StdClass;
$att->parent->id = "11446498";
```

as you can see when encoding it back to `JSON` with PHP:

```
echo json_encode($att);
//outputs: {"name":"tigers.jpeg","parent":{"id":"11446498"}}
```